# Missing assembly reference? Umbraco 7 project in TFS

Tags: .net, tfs, nuget, umbraco, azure-devops

We recently tried to make the move from Mercurial to TFS / Visual Studio online for our source control on projects.

We mainly work with Umbraco and have created several projects and shared them across machines using Mercurial.

In TFS however, we are having nothing but issues.

I have taken our most recent code base and checked it in to the server ensuring I do not commit the bin folder or the packages folder.

All of the DLLS in the bin folder should be rebuilt on the local machine when someone pulls the project down from TFS. Similarly this should also happen with the packages we use from Nuget as our project includes a packages.config file.

This all appears to work as expected however, when I run my solution after building after checking out the latest version from TFS (of which there is only one) I get the following errors:

Server Error in '/' Application.

```
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Ajax' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.Mvc' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Source Error:


Line 22:     using System.Web.WebPages;
Line 23:     using System.Web.Mvc;
Line 24:     using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;
Line 25:     using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
Line 26:     using System.Web.Routing;


Source File: c:\Users\Development Machine\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\32819576\90e5d864\App_Web_home.cshtml.65a2d1ee.g3sjlk5e.0.cs    Line: 24
```

I have checked that the version of Microsoft.Asp.Net.MVC that is located in my packages.config file is the same upon restoration as it should be and it matches correctly however, there are a number of items in my bin folder that have yellow triangles against them signifying a warning.

Does anyone have any clues as to how to rectify these issues as at the moment TFS is looking like a no go despite the exact same project working perfectly when managed in the same way in Mercurial.

Comment: Were you able to build in tge folder before you checked into tfs?

Comment: Yeah I was. The funny thing is that I tried removing the repository from my machine and bringing it back down from the server. It worked. When I tried it with a colleagues machine it wouldn't work after pulling it down. On another colleagues it did. I then tried it on a virtual machine at home and it didn't work so clearly something is amiss.

Comment: Sounds like you have something missing from source that only done people have installed.

Comment: There is nothing missing from source. All packages are installed via NuGet meaning the dependencies are stored in the package.config file of the solution. These are then restored on the external machines.

Comment: Some of the dependency were missing in the nuget package for a while. Fixed latest version 7.2.6 but if your using an older version there could lie your issue.